# Is it possible to hit someone without training?

Tags: self-defense, self-training

I know that training will increase the effectiveness of strikes, but is it still possible to damage someone without training/thinking?

Note: this is not subjective, I am asking if it is physically (objectively) possible and it is a yes or no question.

Comment: Of course. Most people don't train to fight, and physics.

Comment: Welcome to the site HeMan. Simple logic tells us that it is possible to damage someone without training and thinking. Is there something deeper you meant to ask?

Answer (score 3):

Certainly. People throw untrained punches in brawls all of the time, and you need only look at the newspapers to see the number of times some parent has taken a swipe at their kid and caused them injury. It's even very possible to do without intent, turning to point to something and catching someone in the face with your outswung arm.

Answer (score -1):

A fair bit of research has gone into showing that the person who is most likely to kill or injure you in a violent fight has little or no formal training. This is true even if you are trained. He grew up with violence learned in real fights, on the street. His "promotion" was that he survived. And doing time in prison is like a master class in delivering violence.

It is actually the untrained sociopath you should fear the most.

Comment: I've heard things like that said before, but can you provide any of this research?

Comment: The three books I recommended on the other thread you questioned me on have plenty of it. And "research" on this topic is mostly hands-on. Law Enforcement does not keep data on it. But if you look at those authors' backgrounds, you see they know what they are talking about.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually the book When Violence Is The Answer explains it well. An untrained person with a weapon (e.g. knife) and the intent to set an ambush, the willingness to kill have a distinct advantage over trained but unsuspecting people.